# Printing to a Brother printer from VB2013.net using the brother SDK

Tags: printing, vb.net-2010

I have some code that I think should print to my brother printer but it appears to do absolutely nothing. It is driving me mad!!

Anyone any ideas at all please

```
    Dim PrinterName As String = ComboBox1.Text
    If PrinterName.Contains("Brother") Then
        Dim objDoc As bpac.Document
        objDoc = CreateObject("bpac.Document")
        Dim STRlbl As String = "C:\BarcodeScans\Application\Label.lbx"

        If (objDoc.Open("C:\BarcodeScans\Application\Label.lbx")) Then
            objDoc.GetObject("objCompany").Text = Txtbox1.Text
            objDoc.GetObject("objName").Text = Txtbox2.Text
            objDoc.SetPrinter(PrinterName, True)
            objDoc.StartPrint(STRlbl, PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault)
            objDoc.PrintOut(1, PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault)
            objDoc.EndPrint()
            objDoc.Close()
        End If
```

It doesn't fail or error,Steps through every line as it should, it just does not print. 
The label/template prints fine from my PC connected direct to the Brother printer via usb. Printer is a PT-9700PC

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports bpac
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim pkInstalledPrinters As String

        ' Find all printers installed
        For Each pkInstalledPrinters In _
            PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(pkInstalledPrinters)
        Next pkInstalledPrinters

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim PrinterName As String = ComboBox1.Text
        Debug.Print(PrinterName.ToString)
        If PrinterName.Contains("Brother") Then
            Dim objDoc As bpac.Document
            objDoc = CreateObject("bpac.Document")
            Dim STRlbl As String = "C:\Users\...\UPC-A.lbx"
            If (objDoc.Open(STRlbl)) Then
                objDoc.GetObject("tUPC-A").Text = TxtBox1.Text
                objDoc.GetObject("tRetail").Text = TxtBox2.Text
                objDoc.GetObject("tBarCode").Text = TxtBox3.Text
                objDoc.SetPrinter(PrinterName, True)
                objDoc.StartPrint(STRlbl, PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault)
                objDoc.PrintOut(1, PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault)
                objDoc.EndPrint()
                objDoc.Close()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ComboBox1.Text <> "" Then
            Button1.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```